# Html boilerplate in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

So in my razor view file I wanted html boilerplate so I typed html and pressed tab but it isn't working

its been bugging me cause i need to make multiple razor view files and each time copy pasting is not intresting.What to do??

Comment: For html tags to work, you need to reference tag helpers in your code. Please see this link: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers